# How do I obtain residuals and check their normality when conducting a mixed ANOVA in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, anova, mixed

Prior to conducting a 2 (between-group factor: 2 levels) by 2 (within-group factor: 2 levels) mixed ANOVA in R, I would like to test whether the residuals of my outcome variable are normally distributed. This is one of the assumptions of the mixed ANOVA.

My question is: **How** can I obtain the (studentized) residuals of my outcome variable in R?

Help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Q1 is at-home here on Stack Overflow - it's a programming question. However, to be well-answered you should include some sample data - either real, simulated, or built-in to R. Whatever function you're using for the mixed ANOVA may have perfect sample data as an example at the bottom of it's help file - that would be easiest.

Comment: Questions 2 and 3 about what you "should" do would be more at home at Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com). I'd suggest editing this question here to include only (1), with sample data, and moving (2) and (3) to stats.stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas. I will do that!